# Extracting attribute values from an HttpResponse XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, httpresponse

So I've gotten help from here already so I figured why not try it out again!? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using HTTP client and making a POST request; the response is an XML body that looks like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invokeResult>
<method name="RS">
<params>
      <param name="sp" value="" />
      <param name="cp" value="" />
      <param name="ck" value="" />
 </params>
 </method>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
    <status>ENDED</status>
    <reportUrl></reportUrl>
    <runId></runId>
    <pass count="0" />
    <fail count="1" />
    <message>column,report</message>
  </result>
</invokeResult>
```

Now...

I have an HttpEntity which is

```
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

i would like to get the value of `<pass count="0" />` from the xml response through java code. can some one help me pls ?

Detail code i made but getting null pointer exception.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("REQUEST-URL");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && response.getEntity() != null) { 
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            responseString=responseString.replaceAll("<?xml*?>", "").trim();
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                    responseString)));
            NodeList orderNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("<pass count=");
            String strOrdNo = orderNode.item(0).getTextContent();
            logger.info("pass Value = " + strOrdNo);
```

Thanks

Comment: In which line you get the NPE?

Comment: Am getting NPE at
NodeList orderNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("<pass count=");
String strOrdNo = orderNode.item(0).getTextContent();

Comment: You just need to pass the tag name there;  `doc.getElementsByTagName("pass")`. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the `pass` and `fail` are empty tags (the tags closed as `/>`) and they do not hold any value. If you are trying to extract the value of the `count` attribute, you can try the following

```
NodeList orderNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("pass");
String strOrdNo = orderNode .item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue();
logger.info("pass Value = " + strOrdNo);
```

Comment: Wonderful. i got the value now. thank you so much sir.